# Do Zefram Cochrane and Lily Sloane remember what happened in Star Trek: First Contact?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I would think that after the Enterprise E traveled "back to the future" and repaired the timeline, neither Cochrane or Sloane would remember the Enterprise's involvement in achieving first contact. Is that right? Because otherwise doesn't that totally screw up the timeline?

Comment: Why wouldn't they remember it? The attack took place, and nothing altering the timeline actually occurred; the *Phoenix* achieved warp speed at the required time, the Vulcans came to Earth, Cochrane and Sloane made contact, etc.. There is no particular reason for the *Enterprise-E* crew to even suspect that they were not meant to intervene, time-travel being what it is. There was absolutely no reason why Sloane and Cochrane would not remember the events of *First Contact*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In ENT 2x23, [Regeneration](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Regeneration_(episode)), it was confirmed that Zefram Cochrane does indeed remember the events of the movie:

> It is a speech that was given 89 years prior by Human history's inventor of warp drive, Dr. Zefram Cochrane. In it he had spoken about the events surrounding his first warp flight. He had spoken of a group of cybernetic creatures from the future who had intended to "enslave the Human race". They had tried to prevent the flight, but were stopped by a group of Humans, also from the future.

Since he remembers it, it's pretty likely that Lily Sloane does as well.

Comment: And does the Enterprise crew remember the event as well when they travel back into the future?

Comment: @Lukas Why wouldn't they?  They did nothing to erase their own memory...

Comment: Good point, I suppose they just keep it a secret. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Lukas: They don't keep it a secret. They file a report on it, as everyone in the military would.

Comment: That was worded badly, I meant they as in Starfleet Command. Meaning that it probably wouldn't be an occurrence that everyone would be aware of

Comment: @Lukas: Why? Do you have any evidence showing that the civilian population is unaware of the events?

Comment: The events are never mentioned in any other episode as far as I'm aware. In Voyager, the only member of the crew that appears to know about the Borg's temporal incursion into 2063 is Seven of Nine, and that's because she was linked into the hive mind during those events. Also, I feel like the Department of Temporal Investigations would not just let an event like that be known to everybody. They were extremely secretive and displeased with Sisko in the DS9 episode "Trials and Tribble-ations"

Comment: The events of *First Contact* took place after *Voyager* became lost in the Delta Quadrant. The crew cannot, therefore, have any knowledge of those events, outside of Seven of Nine, until they re-establish contact with the Federation.

Comment: @Lukas: The _vast_ majority of happenings within the Federation are never mentioned in any episode.